# Android device doesn't support ARCore but actually can run AR with Vuforia?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, arcore

I was looking the AR tutorial, then I found out one way of it's by using Vuforia. But vuforia is not for free; it has marker on it for sure.
Then I try for another AR tutorial, and I found out about ARCore and ARKit.
because I'm using Android, so I'm going for ARCore.
Then I found out, my device doesn't support for the Google Play Service for AR.

Then I'm wondering, why can I run Vuforia but doesn't even meet the requirement for Google Play Service for AR.
I haven't found the answer yet, so I want to know what's the difference between these two — like can Vuforia do body tracking like ARCore? How can it run well on Vuforia? Did they do something so any device could ignore the requirement for ARCore, or is it two different things?

Comment: In Unity, you set the least required APK to run this application. The least is 4.0 android version. I guess thats the only reason because Unity acts like a base and vuforia uses Unity as a support.

Comment: the minimum api level is set to 4.4 kitkat api level 19 automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vuforia brings its own tracking functionalities and uses them when ARKit or ARCore are not available on a device. What it does is to automatically check on what kind of device it is running. If it does not support ARCore it will switch to it's own tracking functionality. It's not as good as ARCore in my opinion but it enables older devices to use AR.